# C# What is this type of sorted listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I've been looking for a long time and cannot find what type of sorted box this is here:

[image]

If anyone here knows what is the name of this and how can I assign it an ID for example.
In the box I'd like.
Status, Display name, username

but I want the ID of each item to be the username, what I mean by ID is when highlighted I can message that handle.

Comment: This appears to be a `ListView`

Comment: or could be a DataGridView, or a Custom Control, or a 3rd Party Control. It looks nicer than the norm so could be a WPF application, but it's still possible to produce in WinForms - just takes more effort... where did you get the screen shot from?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the ListView control. You need to add icons and columns and put it in detail view.

Start here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bz1s4ky(v=vs.90).aspx

and follow the How-To's, such as this one: How to Add icons to ListView:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4ka5fex(v=vs.90).aspx